# bootstrap navbar flicking on click ( navigation )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a ruby on rails web application and i'm using bootstrap navbar , but the navbar is flicking on navigation !!

screeshots 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Show your code not only image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

l once had a similar problem and l think the problem you are having is caused by you css file conflicting with the bootstrap default styles, try to use the developer tools to and go straight to the box-model at the bottom to see your errors. l hope this helps

Comment: i didn't find errors !! , or i don't understand you !